# How to call a function in Init method?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm new to sapui5, and I'd like to know how to call a function in my Init method?

The code I have currently is below:

```
onInit: function() { 

        this.oInitialLoadFinishedDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();          
        var oEventBus = this.getEventBus();



        this.getView().byId("list").attachEventOnce("updateFinished", function() {
            this.oInitialLoadFinishedDeferred.resolve();
            oEventBus.publish("Master", "InitialLoadFinished", {
                oListItem: this.getView().byId("list").getItems()[0]
            });
        }, this);

        oEventBus.subscribe("Detail", "TabChanged", this.onDetailTabChanged, this);

        //on phones, we will not have to select anything in the list so we don't need to attach to events
        if (Device.system.phone) {
            return;
        }


        this.getRouter().attachRoutePatternMatched(this.onRouteMatched, this);

        oEventBus.subscribe("Detail", "Changed", this.onDetailChanged, this);
        oEventBus.subscribe("Detail", "NotFound", this.onNotFound, this);
        oEventBus.subscribe("Detail", "Cancelled", this.onDetailChangeCancelled, this);

        // this.handleSelectDialogPress();

    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there to call function from init.

For Example, if you want to call some function which is within the same controller then use **'this'** keyword (here **'this'** refers to the current controller):

```
onInit: function() { 
   ...
   this.handleSelectDialogPress();
}

handleSelectDialogPress : function () {
  // some code
}
```

Refer below code if you want to call some function which is in some Utils.js

**ControllerName.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
   "./MyUtils"
], function(Controller, MyUtils) {
   "use strict";

   return Controller.extend("your.controller.ControllerName", {
      myFunc2: function(input) {
         MyUtils.myFunc(input);
      }
   });
});
```

**MyUtils**

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
   "use strict";

   return {
      myFunc: function(input) {
         // some code
      }
   };
});
```